# PHP check if MySQL table contains value

Tags: php, mysql, database

Okay so the title may be a bit misleading. What I am trying to do is add a favorite system to my site. I have one column for my favorite things and I set it up so after each item ID there is a `:`. How can I check the string returned from my database (`1345:13456:232:524378:324`) if it contains `232`? If it does I would echo `preRend` else I would echo `insert` and insert that ID followed by a `:`. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once(".conf.php");
$logged = $_SESSION['logged'];
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$fwdfav = $_POST['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accountController WHERE user='$user'");

if ($logged == 1) 
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($row['fav-itms'] //This is where I got stuck. How to check if it contains a value.)
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO accountController ('fav-itms') VALUES ('$fwdfav')");
            echo 'inserted';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'preRend';
        }

    }
} 
else
{
    echo 'nlog';
}
?>
```

Thank you so much! I am sure there are a lot of errors here as I am very tired.

Comment: **Do not store delimited strings in relational database columns!** Create a *many-to-many* relationship using a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

Comment: The bad idea depends on the system, but supposing you're in charge of the code and DB it is just not a sane way to do it since a relational table is very easy to manage and would absolutely remove the very problem you speak of here. If your site is small then the processing of explode vs a simple join makes no difference, so the rational argument is how sustainable this method is and if anyone else alive would be willing to pick up where you left off. I would be mad if I inherited that method for sure. Especially considering how easy a relational table is to set up and manage.

Comment: @JosephTorraca, What's the point of having a database then?  Why not just dump everything in a 400-column wide CSV?  The answer of course is that you can't easily sort, join, aggregate, or anything else on the data you have in that field.  You're rendering your database useless for that data.

Comment: Because you have created a database schema that not only fails to leverage what a database is designed to do (why the heck use a database?  Just use a flatfile if you want delimited strings), and you are foreclosing on MySQL's ability to do more complex queries with your data.  See my response for an approach that I think is more in line with what @Phil is thinking.

Comment: I should clarify that I say "depends on the system" because I believe cms packages like expressionengine might force very unusual data arrangements where a delimited string was provided in example for their utterly confusing schema. I don't mean that it is right by any means, but that sometimes you can be forced into a "standard" or inherit something you would never make on your own.

Comment: This is a stupid use of mysql, several have already mentioned. Why it's stupid is if you have any need of searching for a substring, getting all rows that match a certain substring or set of substrings. You aren't using the power of an RDBMS if you are doing a ton of string comparisons.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ALL_THE_DATA (DATA VARCHAR(2*1024*1024));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you are taking is extremely inefficient and does not take advantage of the fact that you are using a database.

(Btw... I hope this is just example code; you have a giant SQL injection vulnerability in your INSERT query.)

What I would do instead is create a second table that would look something like:

```
favorites (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    user_id int(11),
    fav_id int(11)
)
```

And have each row represent a user-favorite pair.  Then you can let MySQL do the heavy lifting of figuring out whether a user has favorited something, e.g.,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favorites WHERE user_id = %d AND fav_id = %d;
// Substitute the actual look-up values in using prepared statements
```

You could also similarly quickly get the actual favorites for a user, etc.

Remember, a database is designed for the explicit purpose of storing and looking up information quickly.  PHP is a general-purpose programming language.  Where possible, let MySQL do the walking for you.

(This advice is general for a moderately scaled setup.  If you need to handle millions of simultaneous users, far more optimization is obviously required, and conventional relational databases might not even be suitable.  But I don't get the impression that's where you're at right now.)

Comment: Yes this is just sample code for the sake of explaining what I meant. And you are correct, I am no where near large scale, millions of requests, though I would like to be. Maybe a few years. This is a very good example of how to do a relational database and I think I am going to go use this exact example on my site. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

You could explode it in array as check, like:

```
$yourArr = explode(":", $row['fav-itms']);
$checkFor = 232;
if(in_array($checkFor, $yourArr)) {
  //it exists
}
else {
  //does not exist
}
```

Did you mean something like this

Comment: well, if that solved your problem then could you make it Accepted.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted a while ago but it came up when I did a search.

I have a database storing information for my portfolio, it holds locations for images.

I am working on a page to display the full view of the project. Within the page I need it to check the columns for the images and if any are empty I need it to not display anything.

This is how I've done it.

// connect, select database, query table relevant to page. I have done a query for a specific row.

```
    if($row[columnName1]){
       echo '<div> displaying value </div>';
    }
    if($row[columnName2]){
       echo '<div> displaying value </div>';
    }
```

what is happening, if columnName1 in selected row has a value display the value in div else nothing. then on to column 2.

if it is done like this

```
    if(!$row[columnName1]){
            //content displayed
    }
```

and the column does not contain a value then what is in between the {} will be ran.

Works the way I needed it to, maybe this will help someone.